# Counting surjective functions from set X to set Y?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

The following [problem and solution](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/%7Egennady/hw1.pdf) counts the number of surjective functions from set $X$ to set $Y$.  First, is this solution correct?  I ask because a surjective function can be any number of $x$ in the domain mapped to a $y$ in the co-domain, yet this problem only considers pairs in the domain.

Second, how is the value of $4!=24$ surjective functions arrived at?  This part is confusing to me.

[image: problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution depends on the fact that the domain has one more element than the range.  In this case, if the function is surjective there will be exactly one pair of elements of the domain mapped to the same element of the range.  Once you choose that pair, you have the same number of elements in the domain (if you consider the pair one element).  Now you are looking for a bijection from the first set to the second, where both sets have $4$ elements.  You pick an element from the domain and have $4$ choices for where to send it.  You pick a second, and have $3$ choices where to send it because you can't send it the same place the first went.  The third has $2$ choices and the last has just $1$.  Multiplying gives $4!$.

Comment: The calculation depends on the domain being 1 element larger than the range.  Each of the 10 pairs of the domain make up an element of a same size domain/co-domain bijection where the pair is one element.  $4!$ is the functions from the bijection.  There are 10 different bijections with an element paired.  $4! * 10$ is the solution.